# How to download artifacts from github using maven?

Tags: maven, github

An old legacy project in my team is being salvaged for any usable part, one of its dependency is play-json_2.10 with a version number 2.2. However since its too old, its missing from all the major repository, including typesafe and sonatype central. The only place i can find it is on github:

https://github.com/mandubian/play-json-alone

I could download it and manually save it to a local maven repo but my team mate won't be able to see it after checking out my commit. Is there a way to make maven downloading from github and put source code somewhere? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why not downloading it building it and deploy to your repository manager (assuming you are using one)?

Comment: My team mate is checking out my project as well, so every one of them have to do it again. I don't know if posting somebody else's work to a remote repository manager (like maven central) is a violation of copyright